# Python: Pick other value

Tags: python, list

Please excuse (or improve the title) but I have a silly little problem that's making me very unsure.

I have a list that can contain one to two values, never more, never less and only these two options:

```
options = ['option one', 'option two']
```

As I say, sometimes there may only be one of those values in the list so it might just be `['option two',]`

The scope for this is simple navigation on a website. I accept a querystring entrance and search the list for those options:

```
current_option = request.GET.get('option', options[0])
if not current_option in options: current_option = options[0]
```

If no "option" is provided, it defaults to the first available option.

But now **I want to know what the *other* option is**. If `"option one"` is the input, I want `"option two"`. And if there is only `"option one"` in the `options` list, for example, I want the return to be `False`.

I know I can loop through the list but it feels like there should be a better way of just picking the other value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
options.remove(current_option)
options.append(False)
return options[0]
```

**Edit**: If you don't want to modify `options`, you can also use the somewhat less readable

```
return (options + [False])[current_option == options[0]]
```

Comment: A much better answer than mine. :P

Comment: The second approach is beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

```
current_option = request.GET.get('option', options[0])
if not current_option in options:
    current_option = options[0]
else:
    oindex = options.index(current_option)
    other_option = False if len(options) != 2 else options[(oindex+1) % 2]
```